# Convert ProcessID to Process Handle

Tags: windows, device-driver, wdk, wdm

i am trying write basic driver for monitor process and get process path.
i create `PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine` and retrieve Process information using `ZwQueryInformationProcess`
but in my `ProcessCallback` function when i try to get current process `HANDLE` using `NtCurrentProcess`, it give me current process that run another process .

For Example:

> i try to run myProgram.exe in c:\,when i go to C:\ using windows explorer and run
>    myProgram.exe my
>   driver give me explorer.exe path because myProgram.exe run inside
>   explorer.exe

i have processID in my ProcessCallback header

```
void ProcessCallback(
    IN HANDLE  hParentId, 
    IN HANDLE  hProcessId, 
    IN BOOLEAN bCreate
    )
```

.can i convert it to process handle?

Comment: I'm not certain, but it looks like you should be able to convert a process ID to a process handle using ZwOpenProcess.

Comment: i am trying ZwOpenProcess but i'm not sure this is work perfectly!my driver crash and not run!

Comment: What is the bugcheck on crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks all of you for helpful comment 
finally i solve my problem with below code

```
HANDLE proc = NULL;
OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES obj_attr;
CLIENT_ID cid;

cid.UniqueProcess= hProcessId; //PsGetCurrentProcessId();
cid.UniqueThread= NULL ; //(HANDLE)0;
InitializeObjectAttributes(&obj_attr,NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
ZwOpenProcess(&proc, PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, &obj_attr, &cid);
```